# Can AT+CMGS be cancelled without ESC?

Tags: sms, at-command, sim800

Is it possible to have `AT+CMGS` commands cancelled by some control code other than ESC?

I need it because ESC is intercepted by the attached equipment for its own use and never gets to the modem. And, I can't change that.

Unfortunately, *CTRL-Z* will send even an empty message, or else I could backspace enough to clear the message and do *CTRL-Z* to abort.

The relevant *"AT command set"* manual is no help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [TS 127 005](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/127000_127099/127005/03.01.00_60/ts_127005v030100p.pdf) specification, it seems that there's no way to configure the character for SMS sending abortion.

Anyway I can suggest a workaround, based on three different commands:

- `+CMGW` - Write Message To Memory
- `+CMGD` - Delete Message
- `+CMSS` - Send Message From Storage

So basically, instead of using `+CMGS` that sends the message in one step

1. Write the SMS to memory with `+CMGW` (same syntax of `+CMGS`). After the SMS contents closure with the *CTRL-Z* character, its answer is

   ```
   +CMGW: <index>
   ```

   where `<index>` is the message location index in the current memory storage
2. Actually send it with

   ```
   AT+CMSS=index
   ```
3. Delete the SMS with

   ```
   AT+CMGD=index
   ```

   Since memory slots are limited, you will have to delete it anyway. If you realize that the message you are composing during `+CMGW` phase is wrong, store it anyway with *CTRL-Z* and skip the actual sending.

As you can see, the entire procedure is performed without using the **ESC** character (`0x1B`), can be easily automated and doesn't require much more time to be executed.

Comment: This is one good idea.  I'll wait to see if there are any more suggestions closer to what I want before I mark it as correct.